# Javafx ScrollBar Calculation

Tags: java, javafx

I have vertical scroll bar that controls a scroll pane. 
Within that scroll pane I have several elements in which I know the height of each element and with each click i want to position the scroll pane so that the next element is at the very top of the scrollpane.

For example I know:

```
double element1Height = 100;
double element2Height = 75;
double element3Height = 80;
//etc...
double totalElementsHeight = 1000;

double ScrollPaneHeight = 382;

//I can set the max of the scrollbar to whatever I want. 
double scrollbarVerticalMax = X;
```

On the first click I want to see the top of element2 therefore pixels 100 - 482 in the scrollpane.

What value should I set for

```
 Vscrollbar.setValue(value);
```

Thank you in advance.
Type a message...

Comment: unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. related: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly ;)

Comment: `topY = max(contentHeight - viewportHeight, 0) * value` where `topY` is the min y coordinate in the content visible in the viewport.